# Updating Winform Control From Another Thread and Class C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, user-interface, forward-declaration

I have been struggling with trying to update a Winform control from another thread and another class in C++.  I see several questions about this topic but each one seems incomplete in someway and I can't work out the missing parts.

My Winform thread has a picturebox.  I have a separate class that runs on a separate thread that captures images from a webcam, processes them, and then I want to display the images back on the Winform thread in the picturebox.  I am using VS2010 SE C++.

My code is as follows:

```
//CameraThread.h
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

class Form1;

public class CameraThread
{
    private:
    Form1* frm1;  // compiler does not like this line
    public: CameraThread(Form1 *tfrm1)  {
    frm1 = tfrm1;
    }

void PictureUpdater(void)   {
    try {
        frm1->Invoke( Form1->UpdateBox() );
            }
            catch
            { };
}


//Form1.h
namespace SV7 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    public: delegate void UpdateDelegate(void);

    public:
    Form1(void)  {
              // constructor code
            }

    void UpdateBox(void)  {
        if (this->RawImageBox->InvokeRequired)  {
        UpdateDelegate^ d = gcnew UpdateDelegate(this,&Form1::UpdateBox);
            this->RawImageBox->Invoke(d);
        }
    else {
         // code that actually updates this->RawImageBox
    }
        }
}
```

My Form1 class compiles fine.  However, the CameraThread needs to reference the Form1.UpdateBox method.  When I compile the above code, I am getting an error referring to a "const" where the CameraThread ties to declare a pointer to Form1.  I thought that the forward declaration of Form1 would handle that but apparently not.  My problem seems like one that everybody using a separate thread and class to do significant work from a GUI thread would encounter, so I am hoping that my question will prompt a response that can be used as a template by others.  I am relatively new to multithreading and am not claiming huge expertise in C++ either, so I apologize if this is something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you use different class is not important. It is just the way how you organize your code. You can put everything in one class, make 10 classes, etc. The goal is logically organize your code.

You cannot make any actions on the objects/data fields that are used in the UI thread from any different thread. This will not work. This is plain wrong. Allocate data on the heap on your worker thread, call `PostMessage` with the pointer to this data, pick up your data on your UI thread (directly in your form), process and release this data.

This is how it should be organized.

Comment: Thanks.  I know that you cannot update a control directly from another thread.  That is the reason for the delegate and InvokeRequired check in the code above. Now the issue is, how can I call that method from another thread and class?  What, specifically, is wrong with my syntax? I will have to check the PostMessage approach but I see many questions about the approach I am trying.